# Extending Sencha Touch objects

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm trying to extend the Ext.Container object within the Sencha Touch framework to add a few extra properties I need, one of which is loading a file through AJAX.

```
App.Ext.AContainer = Ext.extend(Ext.Container, {
ajax : false,
doAjax : function(p, that) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : p,
        method : 'POST',
        success : function(result) {
            Ext.apply(that, {
                html : result.responseText
            })
        },
        failure : function(result) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('ERROR : AJAX : Could not load ' + p);
        }
    })
},
constructor : function(b) {

    if( b.ajax === true && b.hasOwnProperty('rhtml')) {
        this.doAjax(b.rhtml, this);
    }

    App.Ext.AContainer.superclass.constructor.call(this, b);

    console.log(this);

}
});
```

With the actual implementation of that Container being :

```
var servicesContainer = new App.Ext.AContainer({
  scroll : 'vertical',
  ajax : true,
  rhtml : 'test.html'
});
```

Basically, my idea was have an method that takes care of loading the file and then copy it to the html property manually. When I check the console from outputting 'this', it shows that the html property is getting set with the correct markup, but it doesn't render the markup to the page.

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `if` inside your constructor. It calls `doAjax`, that in turn calls `Ext.Ajax.request` with the `success` function in its argument. The [`request` function documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/source/Connection.html#method-Ext.data.Connection-request) says:

```
Important: Ajax server requests are asynchronous, and this call will
     * return before the response has been received. Process any returned data
     * in a callback function.
```

This means that instantly the control flow goes back to your constructor, before the load completes (I guess even before the request is sent).

So, at the time `console.log` is called, the request (and the `success` function) isn't executed yet.

**TL;DR**: 
Move the `console.log` call to the `success` function.

Answer (score 0):

Also, there's no need to pass the scope to doAjax, instead:

```
App.Ext.AContainer = Ext.extend(Ext.Container, {
    ajax: false,
    doAjax: function (p) {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: p,
            method: 'POST',
            scope: this,
            success: function (result) {
                this.html = result.responseText;
            },
            failure: function (result) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('ERROR : AJAX : Could not load ' + p);
            }
        })
    },
    constructor: function (b) {

        if (b.ajax === true && b.hasOwnProperty('rhtml')) {
            this.doAjax(b.rhtml);
        }

        App.Ext.AContainer.superclass.constructor.call(this, b);

        console.log(this);

    }
});
```

Comment: I figured it out. Aside from my scope being a little mucky, instead of passing the ajax response to `this.html`, I should have passed it to `this.el.dom.firstChild.innerHTML`.